# how to create a type that contains an array of a specific length, in F#

Tags: f#, dependent-type

I have this type:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MLDataRow =
    {
        [<ColumnName "Label"; LoadColumn(0)>]
        Label: bool
        [<ColumnName "Features"; VectorType(799); LoadColumn(1, 799)>]
        Features: float32 array
    }

    static member Build (label, features: float32 array) = { Label = label; Features = features }
```

I would like to know how I can create an object where the '799' number is a parameter?

for example:

```
let a = MLDataRow.Build (10, true, myData)
```

would be creating an object like:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MLDataRow =
    {
        [<ColumnName "Label"; LoadColumn(0)>]
        Label: bool
        [<ColumnName "Features"; VectorType(*10*); LoadColumn(1, *10*)>]
        Features: float32 array
    }

    static member Build (label, features: float32 array) = { Label = label; Features = features }
```

I assume this has to be done through reflection, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Can you explain the goal more directly? The main problem you'll run into is that attributes have to be mapped by the compiler down to bytes in the metadata that goes with the IL immediately. i.e. there is no programmability at the level you are targeting (Reflection is about calling methods/types and/or walking metadata at runtime, but you are not changing anything about the IL or metadata). Downvote is likely down to the fact tat you have not explained a reasonable problem and/or things you've tried, and/or reason oyu are doing it - it's not answerable as it stands.

Comment: I'm using ML dotnet and I need to provide data where the float32 array has a finite size. However, I have multiple use cases where I need a different size array. So, on one side I need to declare in the type the length of the array, but on the other side, I have multiple scenarios.
Since there is quite a variety of lengths, I'm trying to find out how I can instantiate an object with a pre-set array size taken as a parameter, that's why I was thinking about reflection.

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly, but you can pass length as a value, not type parameter, no?
Otherwise, this could give you some inspiration https://github.com/jackfoxy/DependentTypes

Comment: The issue here is that the ML dotnet lib is expecting the number of columns to be fixed and I have multiple scenarios with different numbers of columns and would like to have a generic solution rather than many copies of the type